# Calling IOfflineFilesCache.IsPathCacheable with Delphi

Tags: delphi

I need to use the method IsPathCacheable in the IOfflineFilesCache interface to check to see if a UNC path is being cached:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Has anyone defined this interface for use in Delphi (I'm using Delphi 2010) or know of another way to achieve this (aside from defining it myself)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI to access offline files: The [`Win32_OfflineFilesItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309196%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class can be used to enumerate them and inspect their properties.

To spare you the hassle of setting up WMI for yourself I would suggest the excellent [Delphi WMI Class Generator](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-wmi-class-generator/). It will generate the unit [uWin32_OfflineFilesItem.pas](http://delphi-wmi-class-generator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/root_CIMV2/uWin32_OfflineFilesItem.pas) containing a wrapper class called `TWin32_OfflineFilesItem` which can be used as follows:

```
uses uWin32_OfflineFilesItem;

var
  OfflineItems: TWin32_OfflineFilesItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
  OfflineItems:= TWin32_OfflineFilesItem.Create;
  for i:= 0 to OfflineItems.GetCollectionCount-1 do
  begin
    OfflineItems.SetCollectionIndex(i);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(OfflineItems.ItemPath);  // <-- this gives the UNC path
  end;
end;
```

(There is one other unit involved, uWmiDelphiClass.pas, which comes with the Delphi WMI Class Generator download.)

You can use the same approach to access the methods of [`Win32_OfflineFilesCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309182%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (which corresponds to `IOfflineFilesCache`). Unfortunately there the method `IsPathCacheable` is missing, thus the need to use above approach.